# Out of memory exception when running data-only script

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

When I run data-only script in SQL Server 2008 R2, it is showing this error:

> Cannot execute script
>   Additional information:
>   Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. (mscorlib)

The size of script file is `115MB` and it's only data .

When I open this script file, it shows:

```
Document contains one or more extremely long lines of text.  
These lines cause the editor to respond slowly when you open the file .  
Do you still want to open the file ?
```

I run schema-only script first and then data-only script .

Is there any way to fix this error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot execute script: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918770/cannot-execute-script-insufficient-memory-to-continue-the-execution-of-the-prog)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved it by using [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) utitlity.

```
sqlcmd -S "Server\InstanceName" -U "instantName" -P "password" -i FilePathForScriptFile
```

For example :

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P 123 -i D:\myScript.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Zey's answer was helpful for me, but for completion:

**If you want to use Windows Authentication just omit the user and password.**

And don't forget the quotes before and after the path if you have spaces.

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -i "C:\Users\Stack Overflow\Desktop\script.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're logged into the domain with the correct privileges and there's only one instance running, you also do not have to provide the above user/pw/instance command args.  I was able to just execute:

sqlcmd -i myfile.sql