# New install: SSMS cannot open new empty query or select top 1000

Tags: ssms

I have a new hp 2010 laptop. SQL Server 2017 and SSMS were installed and it worked.

I then needed to uninstall SQL Server 2017 and reinstall with mixed authentication enabled during the install.

Today my SSMS will not allow me to create a new query and I cannot select the top 1000 records of a table.

I select "New Query" and get the error:

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program. (mscorlib)

I have tried multiple uninstalls and resinstalled this and an older version of SSMS.

I believe SQL Server is running okay.

Any ideas?

Thanks
travelerhj

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918770/cannot-execute-script-insufficient-memory-to-continue-the-execution-of-the-prog

Comment: Yes I reviewed those answers.  Those posts relate to running a large sql query against a database.  I am only trying to open a new empty query.  I fear my issue is due to uninstalling then reinstalling.